# Error when running example_web_connector.php

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks, devkit

I am trying to use quickbooks php webkit to connect my PHP website to quickbooks web connector. However when I run example_web_connector.php in my browser as suggested by http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start, I get the following error.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php
>   on line 56
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/5.5/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master')
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php
>   on line 56

I didn't change any of the files in the devkit folder. The only change I did was adding the connection string to the file.

```
$dsn ='server=localhost;uid=username;pwd=password;database=database';
```

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you without seeing your code. 99% chance you screwed up your connection string.

Comment: Hi Keith, I added my connection string. Still, It's odd that it throws a missing file error though.

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong connection string format! using the format given in the getting started text mysql://YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME:YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD@YOUR_MYSQL_HOSTNAME/YOUR_MYSQL_DATABASE solved the issue for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/.php): **failed to open stream**: ***No such file or directory in ...***

Simple: File Not Found error. Indicating the file to run the code from can not be found.

#### Check your directory structures.